# How to implement verification on the uniqueness of the username and display error in alert in my case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I implement authorization and registration in the application using Fomik and Yup.

I have a local server on my computer. The folder with this server is located near to the folder of my project. I just start the server thanks to the adonis serve command.
When the server is started. I write in the form fields: username, password and others...And then if the validation was successful I press button submit and I get response from my local server.This response contain jwt token.

Now during validation of the form I simply check whether something is written in the username field. But I still need to verification if the username is unique, if not and the username with that name is already registered then display an error in the alert.

How to implement verification on the uniqueness of the username and display error in alert in my case?

Some part of SignupForm.js:

```
const SignupForm = () => {
 const history = useHistory();

    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting} = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
          username: '',
          password: '',
          confirm_password: '',
          first_name: '',
          last_name: '',
          phone:''
      },
        validateOnBlur: false, 
        validateOnchange: false,
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape({    
          username: yup.string()      
           .required('This field is required'),
          password: yup.string()
           .required('This field is required')
           .min(6, 'This password is too short')
           .max(30, 'This passwors is too long'),

        /.......

      }),   
      onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              const res = await api('api/auth/register', {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
              });
              const token = res.token.token;
              localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);
              console.log('Result!',token);
              history.push("/home");  
          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);

          } finally {
              setSubmitting(false);
          }   
      },  
    });

   return (
   <form className="fform" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
       <SignupInput
         label="username"
         id="username" 
         inputProps={{
           name:'username',
           value: values.username,
           onChange: handleChange,
           onBlur: handleBlur,
           disabled: isSubmitting,
       }}
       error={errors.username}

        /.......

       <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>       
   </form>
   );
};
```

Comment: You should do this verification on the server, when you call 'api/auth/register'

Comment: @HermitCrab How to do it? Сan you demonstrate? I've never done that.

Comment: You must store your username in a database on the backend Your register api should check that the provided username is not already registered, if it is, then return an error to the React app and display an error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For async validation, you can use the formik's `validate` function.

**Something like this:**

```js
        ...
        validateOnchange: false,
    validate: (values, props) => {
      return fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          const errors = {};
          // if (res.data() === false) {
          if (res.data.email === "janet.weaver@reqres.in") {
            errors.username = "user already exists !";
          }
          return errors;
        });
    },
    validationSchema: yup.object().shape({
        ...
```

**EDIT**

Working example with a fake api is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-galois-ndbcu?file=/src/components/Signup/SignupForm.js

**Also See docs:**

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation

Comment: i have updated the answer with working example ... let me know if any issues